# At which condition we have to make joomla component, module and plugins

Tags: joomla

Hi i am new in joomla. We have 3 extensions component, module and plugins in joomla. At which condition we have to make module and plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components are basically defining a new type of content beyond the typical Joomla article. Components display their content in the main content area of the template.

Modules are generally used to display content from a component or other source in a template position other than the main content area.

Plugins are generally used to modify or add to the content in a component, module or template. They can also change how the code works within the CMS. They are triggered by various events related to the process of constructing a page to display.

Answer (score 1):

Also u have to read about differences between them.
http://www.dart-creations.com/joomla/joomla-tutorials/the-difference-between-modules-and-components.html

Answer (score 0):

In simple way...

If you need to display any static / dynamic content in template, you use modules.

If you have to create any dynamic page, you have to create components. components are called like index.php?option=com_yourcomponent

plugins are need to change the way components, template or modules work. They are not run independently but triggered by events.

You can either use your own native php codes for development of components/modules. Or follow joomla way ...